# Rnnlib installation range error

Tags: boost, makefile, installation, boost-python, recurrent-neural-network

I am installing rnnlib through https://github.com/meierue/RNNLIB

After installing the boost and other and completing other steps I am getting the error- `SeqBuffer.hpp:227: error: reference to ‘range’ is ambiguous
Helpers.hpp:298: error: candidates are: template<class T> std::pair<boost::iterators::counting_iterator<Incrementable, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default>, boost::iterators::counting_iterator<Incrementable, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default> > range(const T&, const T&)`

```
Makefile:223: recipe for target 'DataExporter.o' failed
make[2]: *** [DataExporter.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/adminhp/Himaanshu/RNNLIB-master/src'
Makefile:217: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/adminhp/Himaanshu/RNNLIB-master'
Makefile:155: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`using namespace` strikes again.

Helpers.hpp contains the following damning sequence:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::assign;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;
```

<strike>Frankly, at this point I'd give up.</strike> Especially the first two lines are the moral equivalent of carpet bombing. With napalm.¹

**UPDATE** Created [a pull request with the changes required to make the code compile](https://github.com/meierue/RNNLIB/pull/2).

To further compound the problem, RNNLIB's `range` facility is not even in a namespace...

So, the upshot is that `range` collides with the namespace from boost.

The simplest way to remove the clash is to qualify all the loopy uses of `range` as `::range`...

> PS. same comes up with `equal` later on

---

¹ [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I've created a pull request that solves the compilation problems: https://github.com/meierue/RNNLIB/pull/2

Comment: I have made the changes you mentioned. But after that I am getting this error.
Helpers.hpp: In function ‘std::pair<boost::counting_iterator<typename boost::range_difference<T>::type, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>, boost::counting_iterator<typename boost::range_difference<T>::type, boost::use_default, boost::use_default> > indices(const R&)’:
Helpers.hpp:301: error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token

Comment: So you didn't apply all the changes :)

Comment: You mean I should also make the changes for "equal" also..?

Comment: Nope. All the changes. Including the ones in Helpers.cpp. And the reorderings. And the qualifications. You know, just the 4 commits in the pull request. I really don't know how to make it clearer than a pull request.

Comment: Okie Yes. Thanks a lot. It worked :). Now I am getting some errors related to make file.
Makefile:223: recipe for target 'Main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [Main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/adminhp/Himaanshu/RNNLIB-master/src'
Makefile:217: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/adminhp/Himaanshu/RNNLIB-master'
Makefile:155: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98229/discussion-between-himaanshu-gauba-and-sehe).